# Can we use TestNG expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp to match the cause text?

Tags: java, testng, http-error

expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp is trying to match the detailMessage field. Can we match the cause text? i.e the text returned by Exception.getCause() ?
This is because the detailMessage field gives very generic message and it will beat the purpose of the test case if expected message is matched with that text.

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = TestExecutionException.class, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = ".* HTTP 422.*")
public void test() throws Exception {
    ..
    //some code that produces TestExecutionException with the cause HTTP 422
    ..
}
```

The TestNG error is:

```
The exception was thrown with the wrong message: expected ".* HTTP 422.*" but got "Failed executing MessageExecutionTask"
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleInvocationResults(Invoker.java:1481)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:754)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 4):

TestNG relies on Reflection to instantiate your test class and then invoke the `@Test` method. So an exception from the `@Test` method would trigger an `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` whose `getCause()` actually results in the exception raised by the `@Test` method.

TestNG is designed to query the `InvocationTargetException.getCause().getMessage()` to get the error message of the exception that was raised and then try and match it using the regex that is supplied via the `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp` attribute of the `@Test` annotation.

Here's an example that runs fine with TestNG `6.12`

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

    @Test(expectedExceptions = OldMonkException.class, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = ".* HTTP 422.*")
    public void test() throws Exception {
        throw new OldMonkException("Your have triggered a HTTP 422 error code.");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTestMethod(ITestResult testResult) {
        String mname = testResult.getMethod().getMethodName() + " ";
        switch (testResult.getStatus()) {
            case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
                mname += "passed";
                break;
            case ITestResult.FAILURE:
                mname += "failed";
                break;
            case ITestResult.SKIP:
                mname += "skipped";
                break;
            default:
                mname += "";
        }
        System.err.println(mname);
    }

    public static class OldMonkException extends Exception {
        OldMonkException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```